# How to use vue in django?

Tags: django, vue.js

Maybe this question sounds silly but still my vue code doesn't want to work. I'm totally new in Vue. I just added script in my  `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>`
And thought it would be enough. Then I wrote the simple piece of code:

```
new Vue({
  el: ".seats_displayer",
  data: { 
   display: "redbox"
  }
})
```

and the caught element:

```
<div class="seats_displayer">
  {{display}}
</div>
```

console says that "display" has not been defined. When I type VUE in console it shows me the vue's object. What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Read [this](https://vsupalov.com/vue-js-in-django-template/)  guide and you should be able to locate where you went wrong.

Comment: @Azy_Crw4282 cool, works now ;)